# Is it possible to install and play adobe flash application/executable/.exe file in Ubislate 7+

Tags: android, flash, flash-cs5

I have developed a small adobe flash application (a parent .exe file which loads several child swf files). I can play it in almost any computer. My question is: Can I install and run the application in Aakash or Ubislate 7+ ?, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

actually no, the android file system uses .APK files that are installed and work with a different structure. but if you worked with Java to create the app, you can port it to android, only changing the UI part of you're application.

Comment: Well, that is a bit disappointing. I have read this:"Ubislate 7+ has 512 MB RAM with maximum 4 to 8 GB intrenal storage, the Aakash tablet Advanced Android Gingerbread 2.3.4 comes with ADOBE FLASH 11. If adobe flash player 11 is there, would it not play swf?

Comment: and this also about Ubislate "•Since the microprocessor is  Cortex A8, It'll surely support Adobe flash player which ensures high quality and fully functional internet browsing."

Comment: yes they can play swf files, but will not recognize the exe file you're using to install

Comment: Thanks, that's encouraging. So, if I publish the whole thing/application as swf (not as exe, i.e., there is a parent swf which loads all child swfs), then my application will play/run in Ubislate???

Comment: If the above (if I publish the whole thing/application as swf (not as exe, i.e., there is a parent swf which loads all child swfs), then my application will play/run in Ubislate???) is true, I have additional query, I have several buttons in parent as well as child swfs. I use mouse to click on buttons. Obviously, there is no mouse in Ubislate, so how the same thing can be done on Ubislate. I mean will my buttons respond to touch??

Comment: Presuming that if I publish the application as swf only (no .exe)i.e., parent swf loads child swfs and it will play in Ubislate, I have an additional query. Both parent swf as well as child swfs have several buttons. I use mouse to click on buttons in a computer. Obviously, Ubislate does not have mouse, so will my buttons work in Ubislate?? Will they respond to touch, how can I make the button to work in Ubislate???

Comment: Thanks again. Right now I don't have Ubislate to test but probably u have guided me in right direction. I saw a tutorial on youtube, most probably this will solve my problem. Take a look: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBs5tehQ5qk&feature=related